# nginx location alias causes error

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm getting an error for nginx with I try to `sudo service nginx reload` with the following included:

```
location /supermarkets.* {
        alias /supermarkets
}
```

What I'm trying to do is if the link is e.g. `111.111.11.11/supermarkets/something` it should redirect to `111.111.11.11/supermarkets`. As context, this is for react-router, I am trying to use browser rather than hash.

Full section

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    #listen 443 ssl default_server;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

        location /supermarkets.* {
                alias /supermarkets
        }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

Comment: What file should the URI `/supermarkets` return? `/var/www/html/supermatkets/index.php`?

Comment: @RichardSmith `index.html` But I can't even get nginx to start (gives error when I run `sudo service nginx reload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nginx -t` to test your configuration and identify syntax errors. Your `location` statement is incorrect syntax and your `alias` statement is missing a terminating `;`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

You may be confusing the function of the `alias` directive, see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

What you are trying to do is usually achieved using a `try_files` directive.

For example:

```
location /supermarkets {
    try_files $uri /supermarkets/index.html;
}
```

The above will check URIs beginning with `/supermarkets`. If the URI matches a local file, it will be returned, otherwise `/supermarkets/index.html` will be returned.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

I notice that your configuration also has a `location ~ \.php$` block which means that any URI beginning with `/supermarkets`, but ending with `.php` will not be directed to `/supermarkets/index.html`.

Comment: yeah, the php files are my backend, this is a react based website, so all the front end stuff will be `.js` or `.css` so that's fine.

Comment: It also didn't work when I tried to do `/supermarkets.*` guess it doesn't need the regex?

Comment: My example uses a prefix location. The regex location requires the addition of a `~` or `~*` operator. But a prefix location is more efficient and all that is required in this case.